# FB.ui With Method "apprequests" not showing all Friends List in Popup (Facebook APP)

Tags: facebook, sdk, apprequests, fb.ui

FB.ui With Method "apprequests" not showing all Friends List in Popup when i invoke this, it is showing my limited friends only (only 6 friends). But when I search in "Search more friends" text box in opened popup window, it display that friend.
I need all friends list in this popup when it opens.

Please Help me out regarding this.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need all?

Comment: Client Requirement.
Please Provide solution.

Comment: There is no solution. It is like that by design

Comment: Is there any change in new FB api? Because I was getting all friend before.